# performing induction on $b_{n+1}=1+\sum_{r=1}^{n}b_{r}^{2}$

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

A sequence is defined by $b_{1}=1$ and $b_{n+1}=b_{n}\left(b_{n}+1\right)$. Prove that for each n: $b_{n+1}=1+\sum_{r=1}^{n}b_{r}^{2}$

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: Vincent Bao Tian, I didn't know where to start

Comment: Also from [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "**Avoid "no clue" questions**.
Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community, which represents a significant waste of time - including for yourself "

Comment: I can't even verify for n=1, some1 please help.

Comment: It is true for $n=1$ because you are assuming that $b_1=1$. That is an assumption, no proof is needed for that. To prove by induction, assume that the formula $b_{n+1}=1+\sum_{r=1}^{n}b_{r}^{2}$ holds for a specific $n$. Now combine this with the formula for $b_{n+2}$ (replace the $n$ by $n+1$ in the constituent formula) to show that the formula holds for $n+1$ (that is, show that $b_{n+2}=1+\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}b_{r}^{2}$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast$ and $k \in \{1,2...,n-1, n\}$:

We have:
$b_{k+1} = b_k^2 + b_k$

Thus:
$ b_{k+1} - b_k = b_k^2 $

Therefore:
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (b_{k+1} - b_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2 $

Therefore:
$b_{n+1} - b_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2 $

Finally:
$b_{n+1} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k^2 $

Comment: See [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)